# Having problems with DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatchertimer

I am having some problems with using some of Dispatcher Timers on a WPF window. 
On a window I would usually use a timer, but this function doesn't seem to be present on WPF forms so I was advised that `DispatcherTimer` was the equivalent.

So I have 3 of these timers:

The first one every 30 seconds brings the form forward - this one works correctly.

```
dispatcherTimer1.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer1_Tick);
dispatcherTimer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
dispatcherTimer1.Start();

private void dispatcherTimer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Topmost.Equals(true);
    this.Activate();
    this.BringIntoView();
    this.Focus();
    this.Topmost.Equals(false);
}
```

The second one keeps checking every 100 milliseconds to see if IExplorer is running and if so hides the OK button and shows a message on the forms telling the user to close IExplorer - When you run the form if IE is running is will disable the button and show the message, but after you close IE it doesn't change it back.

What could i do to get the timer to constantly run and update the form if IE is opened or closed?

```
public Process[] aProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("IExplore");

dispatcherTimer2.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer2_Tick);
dispatcherTimer2.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
dispatcherTimer2.Start();

private void dispatcherTimer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (aProc.Length == 0)
    {
        richTextBox3.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        button1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        button1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        richTextBox3.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

And Thirdly, like the second timer runs every 100 milliseconds, once they have click on the OK button, I want to to kill the IExplorer process in the event that the user tries to invoke it, but again like the second timer is doesn't seem to be running constantly.

Any ideas?

```
dispatcherTimer3.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer3_Tick);
dispatcherTimer3.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
dispatcherTimer3.Start();

private void dispatcherTimer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process[] Processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("IExplore");

    foreach (Process Proc1 in Processes)
    {
        Proc1.Kill();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: That the 2nd and 3rd timer doesn't work correctly, they do not seem to be constantly running, and they are not updating the form as intended

Comment: Do you ever recalculate the `aProc` variable?

Comment: Here is the variable
"public Process[] aProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("IExplore");"

Comment: in timer2 you have to write public Process[] aProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("IExplore"); inside tick event so it changes

Comment: @Shivamcv Right, but without the `public` keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if IE is running is will disable the button and show the message, but after you close IE it doesn't change it back. This is happening because you are not getting process in timer tick event. So change you code as shown below.

```
dispatcherTimer2.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer2_Tick);
dispatcherTimer2.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
dispatcherTimer2.Start();

private void dispatcherTimer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process[] aProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("IExplore"); 
    if (aProc.Length == 0)
    {
       richTextBox3.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
       button1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
       button1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
       richTextBox3.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh OK I get it, thank you very much for the responses

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet, you only get the list of the processes once and then check the same array every time. If it is the same in your real code, make sure you update the process list with each tick.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quiet understand, could you please explain what you mean?